# How to extract specific fields recursively from json output?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

Below is the sample json document or json variable I have. I'm using python for extracting the required fields as mentioned int the output section.

Can someone help on how to do this?

```
json_variable = 
    {  
       "server01":{  
          "address":"server01:5454",
          "options":{ },
          "state":"online"
       },
       "server02":{  
          "address":"server02:5454",
          "options":{ },
          "state":"online"
       },
       "server03":{  
          "address":"server03:5454",
          "options":{ },
          "state":"online"
       }
    }

 for x in json_variable:
        print(x["address"])

    Error:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 30, in <module>
      File "<string>", line 18, in getServerStatus
      TypeError: 'shell.Dict' object is not iterable
```

I can get the required output by hard coding the fields as below, but i would like to do it dynamically as the number of servers vary depending upon the system queried and json returned.

```
print(json_variable["server01"]["address"])
print(json_variable["server02"]["address"])
print(json_variable["server03"]["address"])
```

**Required Output**:

```
server01:5454 --> online 
server02:5454 --> online
server03:5454 --> online
```

Comment: To do this generically, you're going to have to at least hardcode the _patterns_ to look for so the code has a clue as to what you're interested in retrieving. Not sure why you seem to think it needs to be done recursively, however.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `for server in json_variable.values(): print(f"{server['address']} --> {server['status']}")`

Comment: @KlausD. I added the code that I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way to get the server status from the JSON.

```
json_info = {
     "server01":{
     "address":"server01:5454",
     "options":{ },
     "state":"online"
   },
     "server02":{
     "address":"server02:5454",
     "options":{ },
     "state":"online"
  },
     "server03":{
     "address":"server03:5454",
     "options":{ },
     "state":"online"
  }
}

for server in json_info.values():
  server_status = server['state']
  if 'online' in server_status:
      server_name = server.get('address')
      print ('{} is online'.format(server_name.split(':')[0]))
      # output 
      # server01 is online
      # server02 is online
      # server03 is online
      # 
      # print ('{} --> online'.format(server_name))
      # output 
      # server01:5454 --> online
      # server02:5454 --> online
      # server03:5454 --> online
  else:
      server_name = server.get('address')
      print('{} is offline'.format(server_name.split(':')[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Treat it as a dictionary:

```
for k, v in sample.items():
      print(v['address'] + "-->" + v['state'])
```